# Missing Itemid on url at login pages

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I'm on Joomla 2.5.

I created a menu item named "Login Form" with Itemid=626 . Also I created a menu item named "Article" with access level "Registered".

**The Problem**

When a user click on the "Article" menu item on the frontend, he goes to login page

```
index.php?option=com_users&view=login
```

I need this url to contain Itemid=626 so it could be

```
index.php?option=com_users&view=login&Itemid=626
```

Please advise

Comment: you must not set access level "Registered" to your "article". You cannot request people to be logged in to see the login form. Right?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't override standard joomla login page just creating a menu item.

To create easily some rules and redirect the users you can use this component, [Chameleon](http://www.metamodpro.com/chameleon/chameleon).

If you don't need complex rules you can just auto redirect all users from standard login to your page.

Comment: How can I make your last suggestion "f you don't need complex rules you can just auto redirect all users from standard login to your page."?